# Can any one tell me how to crash tomcat deliberately with java out of heap exception

Tags: java, static, tomcat7, out-of-memory, jvm-crash

I am looking for a code which will deliberately crash my Tomcat Server.

---

**EDIT** (moved from comments)

I did this but it still doesnot crash

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); 
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) 
{ list.add(new Object()); }
```

---

I have tried static Lists, HashMaps but I am still not able to cause java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Thanks

Comment: You can try using recursion or infinite loop

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Code?

Comment: Just create some huge array of some objects.

Comment: Already answered@http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261513/how-to-make-outofmemoryerror-occur-on-linux-jvm-64bit

Comment: Try squaring `MAX_VALUE`

Comment: Any exception that you create from within your code (servlet, JSP, whatever) will almost certainly be trapped by Tomcat. App-servers are designed *not* to crash as a result of a poorly-behaved program.

Comment: What is the *real* problem that you're trying to solve? Are you seeing *real* crashes in production? If yes, then edit your question with appropriate information.

Comment: I am just looking for a piece of code which will crash my server, and it wont be able to handle any more requests after that

Comment: That's not a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Better than dealing with the code itself, reduce the maximum heap size.

Look for `-Xmx` on your tomcat bin directory and replace whatever value it has with `-XmxXXXm` where `XXX` is how many MB will the heap be allowed to get.

Comment: I do not want to change the size. I am testing the tomcat as it is